# How to interactively switch between plots, or selectively hide and show data on a plot, in matplotlib?

Tags: python, button, plot, matplotlib, png

I would like to have a button which switches the plot that is being displayed from one set of subplots to another, so someone can easily switch between them to compare differences visually.  If I create several figures, Is there a way to display a button which selects which figure  is being displayed?  Or is there  a way to interactively selectively display and hide only a subset of data  vectors on a plot?

Comment: Side by side or one over the other doesn't work?

Answer (score 7):

Indeed, this can be done with matplotlib [event handling](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/event_handling.html) and a little trick from [animation](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/animation_api.html) (calling `set_ydata` to change the plot).

For example, this toggles between two plots when you click the mouse:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import itertools

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
y1 = np.random.rand(10)
y2 = np.random.rand(10)
ys = itertools.cycle((y1,y2))
line, = ax.plot(next(ys))

def onclick(event):
    line.set_ydata(next(ys))
    fig.canvas.draw()

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
plt.show()
```

---

You could get fancier with the `onclick` function. For example, you could use it to display thumbnails of all your plots, and then on the next click, use the position of the mouse to determine which plot was selected. Then display that plot.